# converting old login using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am a new web developer currently working on a site that is using a login system that does not use any ajax and I would like to convert the existing framework to utilize ajax if that is possible.  Currently it is simply a form that is calling actions already:

```
<form action="<?=$url_root?>/controllers/UserController.php" method="post" name="login_form">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="path_requested" value="<? if(isset($GLOBALS['path_requested'])) { echo $GLOBALS['path_requested']; } ?>" />

<p class="field"><?if(isset($invalid)){?><span class="invalid">Invalid login! Try again.</span><?}?>E-mail:</p>
value="<? if(isset($email)) { echo $email; } ?>" />

<p class="field"> Password:</p>
<input type="password" name="password" onKeyPress="return submitenter(this,event)" tabindex="2"/>

<input class="image" type="image" src="<?=$url_root?>/style/images/img_button_submit.jpg" name="Submit" value="Submit" />


<!--<input type="submit" class="button"/>-->
</form>
```

As it stands right now the form submits to UserController.php and shows a blank screen, and then if its successful it logs in, if not it refreshes back to a certain page.

I would like to convert this where ajax calls the UserController.php in the background and then returns its response.

I started with just a simple form to replace the above form:

```
<form method="post" name="login_form">
<span class="throw_error"></span>
<p class="field">E-mail:</p>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<p class="field">Password:</p>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br><br>
<input class="image" type="image" src="<?=$url_root?>/style/images/img_button_submit.jpg" name="Submit" value="Submit" />


<!--<input type="submit" class="button"/>-->
</form>
```

And here is my ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#login_form').submit(function() {
       checkLogin();
    });

    function checkLogin()
    {
         $.ajax({
            url: "../controllers/UserController.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                email: $("#email").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response == 'true')
                {
                    window.location.replace("main.html");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('bad login');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

I'm not sure how to return the response from UserController.php into the success or failure of the ajax call.  I'm not sure if working with old code requires a total overhaul as well.  Thanks for any input.

Comment: I don't see what benefit this will have to the end user. At most, it will avoid a reload on a failed login, but successful logins will still require two requests (one to verify login, another to go to main.html).

Comment: The code you have so far is close, you just need to prevent the submit event from actually submitting the form, and then replace the alert with something more appropriate. Looks like all you have left is to modify the UserController to respond appropriately. This whole thing though just looks like a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form id="login_form">
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login_form').submit(function() {
        checkLogin();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**AJAX** (if path is http://example.com/example/controllers/UserController.php)

```
url: "/example/controllers/UserController.php",
```